# Disregard word order when comparing two variables

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to compare two variables using shell.

```
$a="abc pqr mno xyz"

$b="mno pqr xyz abc"
```

Here two variable values are same (just words order is not same inside the variable). If i compare `$a` and `$b` it will say that `$a` and `$b` are not same, but I want the shell command to compare and say both contents are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define our variables:

```
a="abc pqr mno xyz"
b="mno pqr xyz abc"
```

Now let's define a helper function which puts the words in alphabetical order:

```
sorted() {  echo "$1" | sed 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/\n/g' | sort; }
```

Now, using our helper function, lets test for equality:

```
[ "$(sorted "$a")" = "$(sorted "$b")" ] && echo Equal
Equal
```

#### Example of unequal strings

```
$ a="abc pqr mno xyz mmm"
$ b="mno pqr xyz abc"
$ [ "$(sorted "$a")" = "$(sorted "$b")" ] && echo Equal
$
```

As an example of what `sorted` does, let's look at its output alone:

```
$ a="abc pqr mno xyz mmm"
$ sorted "$a"
abc
mmm
mno
pqr
xyz
```

As the above shows, `sorted` puts all the words in alphabetical order.

#### Displaying a message in both cases

The following will also display `Not Equal` if the strings are not equal:

```
if [ "$(sorted "$a")" = "$(sorted "$b")" ]; then echo Equal; else echo Not Equal; fi
```

Or, in multiple lines:

```
if [ "$(sorted "$a")" = "$(sorted "$b")" ]
then 
    echo Equal
else
    echo Not Equal
fi
```

Because `echo` always returns true, the following will also work:

```
[ "$(sorted "$a")" = "$(sorted "$b")" ] && echo Equal || echo Not Equal
```

#### sorted and bash

This question is tagged just plain `shell`.  If, however, the shell is bash, then one could define a `sorted` function without the use of sed as follows:

```
sorted() {  echo "${1// /$'\n'}" | sort; }
```

This function differs slightly from the previous one in that only blanks, not tabs or other whitespace, are allowed as word separators and that multiple spaces are not merged into one word break.

Comment: Thanks for the help but if i set a="abc pqr mno xyz mmm" and compare with $b using your command still it says Equal. It shouldnot be equal right?

Comment: @MAHADEVASWAMYHN They compare _unequal_ for me.  I copied and pasted the test results for that string to the end of the answer.  Does your screen show something different?

Comment: This is fairly elegant, but not very general.  If the strings contain shell metacharacters, using the string unquoted (which is a must in order for `printf` to do its job) can cause problems.

Comment: @John1024: Thanks for the response. in my case any one of the variable may have extra words or same. if $a and $b are same it should echo "Equal" else if any one of the variable having any extra character it should say "Not Equal". how can i do that?

Comment: @MAHADEVASWAMYHN I added code to print `Not Equal`.  I also corrected a typo in the `sorted` function: my apologies if that was what caused you difficulty.

Comment: @tripleee Other versions of `sorted` could certainly be written but I was unable to find any combination of metacharacters that would "cause problems" for the current version.  For example, I tried `sorted 'def $(date); <in >out false;|true abc|&;()<> xyz'` and it worked just fine.

Comment: http://ideone.com/GEFZ37 ... With `sorted () { printf '%s\n' $* | sort; }` I get the expected output, though; but not with `a='*'`.

Comment: @John1024: Your code is working fine. Great Thanks John